# How to associate a lead with a campaign by php salesforce api

Tags: leads, php, campaign

I can create lead via salesforce php api toolkit , by my client said every lead should be associated with a campaign , and he gave me a campaign id . The campaign id is similar to something like this "701g0000000Irtl"  . I tried  something like this

```
 $records = array();
 $records[0] = new stdclass();
 $records[0]->FirstName= $user_first_name;
 $records[0]->LastName= $user_last_name;
 $records[0]->Email= $user_email;
 $records[0]->Company= 'MYCompany';
 $records[0]->PostalCode= $current_user_zip;
 $records[0]->Newsletter_Signup__c= $news_letter_sign_up;
 $records[0]->Campaign= "701g0000000Irtl";
 $response = $mySforceConnection_enterprise->create($records, 'Lead');
```

But it doesn't a crate a lead with a campign id . But If I remove the line **$records[0]->Campaign= "701g0000000Irtl";** It works fine , it create a lead in salesforce without any campaign associated with it .

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Campaign_ID" instead of "Campaign"
And don't forget to include "member_status" to give the campaign member, well, a status.

Comment: I tried the "Campaign_ID"  ,  but it gives an error  "No such column 'Campaign_ID' on entity 'Lead'. "

Comment: Try "CampaignID"? That's all I can think of.